# Search form using mongoose, express and node.js. Error: can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I'm trying to do a search using as a reference a field from the Monitoria collection, I'm using a form with its own route and as method GET, but I'm not getting it, I get this error and this message in the route:

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8YD7.png)

[Message in the route. "Pesquisar" it's search in portuguese](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4Nne.png)

The route with the code: ("Pesquisar" it's search in portuguese)

```
  app.route('monitorias/pesquisar')
    .get(function(req, res) {
      //var monitoria = req.body.nomeMonitoria;
      //console.log(monitoria);
      Monitoria.find({name: req.body.nomeMonitoria}, function(err, monitoria) {
        if (err) {
          res.json(err);
        } else {
          //res.render('result', {"monitoria": monitoria[0]} );
          console.log(monitoria);
        }
      });
    });
```

The form in html file: ("Pesquisar" it's search in portuguese)

```
 <form action="/monitorias/pesquisar" method="get" class="form-inline">
     <label class="sr-only" for="nomeMonitoria">Monitoria</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nomeMonitoria" name="nomeMonitoria" placeholder=" Name of Monitoria...">
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
 </form>
```

and the schema of Monitoria:

```
var MonitoriaSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: 'Por favor, entre com o nome da monitoria'
  },
  code: {
    type: String,
    required: 'Por favor, entre com o código da monitoria',
  },
  oferta: {
    type: String,
    default: '2017-02'
  },
  local: {
    type: String,
    default: null
  },
  googlemaps: {
    type: String,
    default: null
  },
  Horarios: {
    type: [String],
    default: null
  }
});
```

I've been stuck in it for many hours. I appreciate any help.

Comment: You have the response commented out.  Is that on purpose?

Comment: do it: res.render('result', {"monitoria": monitoria[0]} ); remove //

Comment: I put that part commented on purpose, so I can better analyze what was happening with the req

Comment: Without comments the error is the same and the api falls.

Comment: I don't think any of the code above is causing your issue ... you have a line of code, probably in your express configuration where you are setting the response header after the response is already sent .... try to find `res.setHeader` or just find `setHeader` ... you will find one added in wrong place ... or if you can post your express configuration code

Comment: @AmrLabib I'll check this out now

Comment: The error `CastErrror` at `"path: _id"` ( which is shown in the image link ) suggests that in fact you have a route defined as `'/monitorias/:id'` or similar naming as well. And in fact it is this router that is being picked up and the value `"pesquisar"` is being passed through from `req.params` and eventually into the the model as the presumed `_id` field, where it is not of course an `ObjectId`. So your routes appear to have a "precendence" problem in that the wrong endpoint is being matched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED!

The route it's wrong:

`app.route('monitorias/pesquisar')` -> `app.route('/monitorias/pesquisar')`

and the req parameter its wrong too, in the function change `req.body.nomeMonitoria`  for `req.query.nomeMonitoria`

So:

```
app.route('monitorias/pesquisar')
    .get(function(req, res) {
      Monitoria.find({name: req.query.nomeMonitoria}, function(err, monitoria) {
        if (err) {
          res.json(err);
        } else {
          res.render('result', {"monitoria": monitoria} );
        }
      });
    });
```